# Adding multiple controls to a Textboxs Control Property in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6 and C# 6.0 and I'm trying to create a control which should look like the one for attached files in an Outlook-Email: A Textbox where filenames are shown which represents a link to the file. With double-clicking into one of the filename, the file will open. With having the cursor inside the textbox and pressing the "delete"-key, the filename will be removed.

At the moment I created a Textbox. To add a filename, a LinkLabel will be created and added to the Controls-Collection of the Textbox (Textbox.Controls.Add(...)).

For one filename, it works fine. But when I add another LinkLabel to the controls, the second one will be shown behind the first one. Why? And how can I handle it? It doesn#t make sense to display them behind each other... I want to have them next to each other..

Also what exactly happens with adding a control to the textbox in the background?

Comment: It's just how controls layout works in WinForms. With `container.Controls.Add(newControl)` you'll place new control **before** the others (in visualization, it's last in the control list). To place it at beginning you should **also** call `container.Controls.SetChildIndex(newControl, 0)`. Note that you should make container (I guess it's a `Panel`, not a `TextBox`) `AutoSize` and docked top otherwise it won't grow-up when you have more children than its width. Side question: You're using VS2k15 to create a WinForms application? Hmmmmmm I'd consider to use a modern and supported technology...

Comment: You could place a **FlowLayoutPanel** into the TextBox. Then place your labels etc. inside that LayoutFlowPanel

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Do you mean WPF? ;-) yeah, but it's my first time with C# and I'm trying first with the WinForms and get later another look into WPF.. So but my problem is still not solved. I don't want to set the child index, because they just set a control in the front of another and not next to it, like within horizontal layout...

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih: It's not the behaviour I want. I already found out, that I can set the location of my LinkLabel-Controls so that they are placed next to each other. That works fine. But I want that I can set the focus inside my Textbox and it should work like a Textbox. So that I can delete my elements with the backspace key. Just like the Textbox of attached files in an outlook email...